Mellin transform of exponential and logarithm
I am trying to calculate the Mellin transform of the function $f(x) = e^{-ax}\ln\left(1+x\right)$. The mathematica gives me the answer
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}f(x)dx = \frac{G_{3,5}^{5,2}\left(\frac{a^2}{4}\Bigg|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1-s}{2},-\frac{s}{2},1-\frac{s}{2} \\
 0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-s}{2},-\frac{s}{2},-\frac{s}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)}{4 \pi ^{3/2}}$$
But I don't know how to analytically obtain the answer myself. I tried this way
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax}\ln(1+x)x^{s-1}dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}a^{-s}\Gamma(s)x^{-s}ds\right)\ln(1+x)x^{s-1}dx\\
=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}a^{-s}\Gamma(s)ds\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx$$
However, turned out that last integral in $x$ diverges! I don't know how to proceed!
Thank you in advance!
